# How to take a Python function and create a simple Tkinter gui for it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have three functions 2 of which take a string and return a string. I have a third function that takes two strings and returns a string. I am trying to create a simple Tkinter GUI that would take in any parameters of the functions then based on the button press run my algorithm returning the result. Tkinter is giving me a hard time. I need four input fields for all possible parameters then run the correct function on press of button. Functions will look like:

CalculateStrenghtofBrute(Word, Charset)
CalculateDictionary(Word)
CalculatePassPhrase(Phrase)

All return a string created within the functions.

Below is a Sample Function

```
def wordTime(Password):

    with open('Dics/dict.txt','r') as f:
    Words = f.read().splitlines()

    found = Words.index(Password)
    found += 1
    timeSec = found*.1
    if(timeSec> 31536000):
        time = timeSec/31536000
        timeType = 'Years'
    elif(timeSec>86400):
        time = timeSec/86400
        timeType = 'Days'
    elif(timeSec>360):
        time = timeSec/360
        timeType = 'Hours'
    elif(timeSec>60):
        time = timeSec/60
        timeType = 'Minutes'
    else:
        time = timeSec
        timeType ='Seconds'


return ('Cracking',Password,'using dictionary attack will take', round(time, 2), timeType+'.')
```

Thanks

Comment: please include some of your code, its very hard to visualize what you're trying to achieve without seeing it

Comment: You're asking us to write a password cracking GUI for you? And what do you mean by "Tkinter is giving me a hard time"?

Comment: NO, I just need an example of using Tkinter to get a string from a user and run it though a function which returns to tkinter the result string. I already have my password crack time functions.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the entry fields the user inputs to my functions when the corresponding button is pressed. Also, not sure how to get my output to the tkinter widget after the function has run.

Comment: @user1376030: show us what you've tried and we can point out how to make it better. Or, spend half a day with a Tkinter tutorial. That should be more than enough time to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: Ugh it is too late for that I have presentation tomorrow GUI-less. I tried a web GUI but was unpredictable and returned wrong values given formulas. Looks like I will just fail. I graduate this semester or would have this lack of GUI will cause me a lot of shame. I went to Iraq for a year and no one can show a simple example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take input from the user you need to create an entry box, once you have an entry box you can call the get method on it to get the string which currently resides in the entry box, I've took your example function and made a simple tk GUI for it:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def wordTime():
    password = input_box.get()
    with open('Dics/dict.txt','r') as f:
        Words = f.read().splitlines()
        found = Words.index(Password)
        found += 1
        timeSec = found*.1
        if(timeSec> 31536000):
            time = timeSec/31536000
            timeType = 'Years'
        elif(timeSec>86400):
            time = timeSec/86400
            timeType = 'Days'
        elif(timeSec>360):
            time = timeSec/360
            timeType = 'Hours'
        elif(timeSec>60):
            time = timeSec/60
            timeType = 'Minutes'
        else:
            time = timeSec
            timeType ='Seconds'
    print ('Cracking',Password,'using dictionary attack will take', round(time, 2), timeType+'.')

# Make a top level Tk window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cracker GUI v.01")
# Set up a Label
grovey_label = tk.Label(text="Enter password:")
grovey_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
# Make an input box
input_box = tk.Entry(root,width=10)
input_box.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10,pady=10)
# Make a button which takes wordTime as command,
# Note that we are not using wordTime()
mega_button = tk.Button(root, text="GO!", command=wordTime)
mega_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
#Lets get the show on the road
root.mainloop()
```

If you wanted to take multiple values you could use multiple buttons which set multiple variables, also I'm not sure about your function but that's not really the question at hand.

For reference the following sites have some good basic examples:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/448-s04/448-standard/simple_gui_examples/